# Failed to deploy Play Store on bitrise with Error 400: Invalid JSON payload received

Tags: bitrise

I am using bitrise to build and deploy my react native code.
Now I am facing the error "Error 400: Invalid JSON payload received" while deploying .aab files to Play Store.

This is my workflow (only google-play-deploy step)

```
    - google-play-deploy@3.0.1:
        inputs:
        - service_account_json_key_path: "$BITRISEIO_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_URL"
        - package_name: my.android.packageName
```

And Logs

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

| (11) google-play-deploy@3.0.1                                                |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id: google-play-deploy                                                       |
| version: 3.0.1                                                               |
| collection: https://github.com/bitrise-io/bitrise-steplib.git                |
| toolkit: go                                                                  |
| time: 2020-03-06T00:12:18Z                                                   |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                              |
Getting configuration
Configs:
- JSONKeyPath: *****
- PackageName: my.android.packageName
- AppPath: \n/bitrise/deploy/app-release20200306001055-bitrise-signed.aab
- ExpansionfilePath: 
- Track: alpha
- UserFraction: 0
- WhatsnewsDir: 
- MappingFile: 
Found .aab file: /bitrise/deploy/app-release20200306001055-bitrise-signed.aab
Configuration read successfully
Authenticating
Authenticated client created
Create new edit
Failed to perform edit insert call, error: googleapi: Error 400: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "": Root element must be a message., invalid
|                                                                              |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| x | google-play-deploy@3.0.1 (exit code: 1)                       | 12.06 sec|
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
| Issue tracker: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-google-play-deploy/issues |
| Source: https://github.com/bitrise-io/steps-google-play-deploy               |
+---+---------------------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

Actually, I have not changed any settings, and before I could upload my .aab file into Play Store Console.

Also I have read this plugin's code(https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-google-play-deploy/blob/master/main.go#L155). 
I assume that the request body is not correct and I could find where creates request body (https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-google-play-deploy/blob/27e5ba1a046cf0a02c17ae50a64a47186ee9cce8/vendor/google.golang.org/api/androidpublisher/v3/androidpublisher-gen.go#L2914).
However, I could not get the cause of this issue because

Does anybody know or have solved this issue?

Comment: Now I tried re-run the script with changing the plugin's version set to latest, and the it is succeeded...

Comment: have you try this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55855697/how-to-fix-the-invalid-json-payload-received-unknown-name-error

Comment: Thanks for your information, I did not try it, I just try to update the plugin and re-run it, then I could get success.